# How to handle call waiting in IncallService

Tags: call

Using incallservice I successfully replaced the caller screen. I am able to call and receive calls. But a problem occurs when the second call is in waiting stage. I tried searching the forum but I found no help on how to handle call waiting.

Currently I am handling call waiting by totally ignoring it.
Alternatively I tried disconnecting it in the background as I am only interested in getting a number of waiting calls. I tried the following

```
public class CallService extends InCallService {


private BroadcastReceiver headsetReceiver = null;

@Override
public void onCallAdded(Call call) {
    super.onCallAdded(call);

    Log.d("bbbbbb", "inside");
    if (constants.CALL_IN_PROGRESS == false) {
        new OngoingCall().setCall(call);
        CallActivity.start(this, call);
    }else {
        call.disconnect();
    }
}




@Override
public void onCallRemoved(Call call) {

    super.onCallRemoved(call);
    handy_methods hm = new handy_methods(this);
    String saved_number = hm.read_sharedpreference("incomingNumber");
    String latestCallNumber = call.getDetails().getHandle().toString().replace("tel:%2B", "+");
    if (saved_number.equals(latestCallNumber.replace("tel:", ""))) {
        Log.d("aaaaaa", "s5");
        new OngoingCall().setCall(null);
    }
}

}
```

}

but call.disconnect() is not handling the waiting call. I just want to disconnect the second call. Can anyone please help me.

Thank you